# Inputting text file and list of words and print corresponding words with lines numbers?

Tags: python, file

This is my code. This only works for one word though and it prints the same word twice.
How can I make it so that it goes through the list of words and through the text file and print the words with their number lines. For example:

```
index (‘raven.txt’, [‘raven’, ‘mortal’, ‘dying’, ‘ghost’, ghastly’, ‘evil’, ‘demon’])

ghost   9

dying   9

demon   122

evil     99, 106

ghastly  82

mortal   30
```

My code:

```
filename = input("type a filename:")
file = open(filename)
counter = 0
lst = []
while True:
   x = input("type word:")
   for line in file.readlines():
       counter += 1
       if line.find(x) >= 0:
           print(x, counter)
```

Answer (score 1):

By using sets you can more or less check of all the keywords at once without looping.

```
def index(filepath, keywords):
  # Convert list to a set
  keys = set(keywords)
  data = {}
  with open(filepath, "r") as fd:
    for i, line in enumerate(fd.readlines()):
      for key in set.intersection(keys, set(line.split())):
        data.setdefault(key, []).append(i)
  return data

filepath = raw_input("Enter file: ")
keywords = raw_input("Enter keywords: ").split()
data = index(filepath, keywords)

for key in sorted(data.keys()):
  print "%s :: %s"%(key, ", ".join([str(i) for i in sorted(data[key])]))
```

With the test file below the output will be:

```
>python kaka.py
Enter file: test.txt
Enter keywords: help some test
help :: 3, 7
test :: 0, 3, 7
```

#### test.txt:

```
ssdfsdf test sdfsdf
sdf
sdfsdfs
sdf help test

sdfsdf

sdfsdf help test
```

Answer (score 0):

`file.readlines()` returns a generator. Items in a generator can be accessed only once. In order to access the iterms in a generator again, you will have to reinitialize it.

Instead you can add all the lines of the file in a list and then search through this list every time a word is input to the program.

```
filename = input("type a filename:")
file = open(filename)
files_lines = [line for line in file]
counter = 0
while True:
    x = input("type word:")
    for line in files_lines:
        counter += 1
        if line.find(x) >= 0:
            print(x, counter)
    # Reset the counter so that for the next search 
    # word the line number begins from line number = 0
    counter = 0
```

You can further improve the code by using [enumerate](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/functions.html#enumerate)

```
filename = input("type a filename:")
file = open(filename)
files_lines = [line for line in file]
while True:
    x = input("type word:")
    line_nos = []
    for line_no, line in enumerate(files_lines, start=1):
        if line.find(x) >= 0:
            line_nos.append(line_no)
    if line_nos:
        print(x, line_nos)
```

Comment: It works! But I want it to append all the words I input into a list first  then look through that list and print the words along with its line number. I do not want the words to repeat in multiple lines. How can I do so that the words occurring on multiple lines print on one line like the ones shown down below

    For example:

    fire 2,4,7

    water 3,1